# Handling multiple exceptions in CBV Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way I can handle both the exceptions from different models and still pass none as context individually.

Views.py

```
class ProfilePage(DetailView):
    model = models.UserCreation
    context_object_name = 'profile'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfilePage, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username=UserCreation.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')))
        print(self.request.user,user,self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        try:
            context['data'] = ProfileData.objects.get( user=user)
            context['userdata'] = User.objects.get( username=user)
            context['creationdata'] = UserCreation.objects.get(user=user)
            context['friends'] = Friends.objects.get( user=self.request.user,added=user)
            context['sorted'] = sorted(chain(AddStatus.objects.filter(user=user), ImageLib.objects.filter(user=user)),
            key=lambda instance: instance.date, reverse=True)
        except ((ProfileData.DoesNotExist as e) or (Friends.DoesNotExistas as f)) :
            if e:
                context['data']= None
            elif f:
            context['friends'] = None
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use two `try`-`except` scopes. In fact it is better *not* to write long `try`-`except` scopes, since then it is no longer clear what triggers the exception. So you can implement this like:

```
try:
    context['data'] = ProfileData.objects.get( user=user)
except ProfileData.DoesNotExist:
    context['data']= None

context['userdata'] = User.objects.get( username=user)
context['creationdata'] = UserCreation.objects.get( user=user)

try:
    context['friends'] = Friends.objects.get( user=self.request.user,added=user)
except Friends.DoesNotExist:
    context['friends'] = None

context['sorted'] = sorted(
    chain(AddStatus.objects.filter(user=user),
    ImageLib.objects.filter(user=user)),
    key=lambda instance: instance.date, reverse=True
)
```

In case having *multiple* `ProfileData`s, etc. is not a problem, you can make use of `.first()` instead that will return `None` if there is no row to return:

```
context['data'] = ProfileData.objects.filter(user=user).first()

context['userdata'] = User.objects.get(username=user)
context['creationdata'] = UserCreation.objects.get(user=user)

context['friends'] = Friends.objects.filter( user=self.request.user,added=user).first()

context['sorted'] = sorted(
    chain(AddStatus.objects.filter(user=user),
    ImageLib.objects.filter(user=user)),
    key=lambda instance: instance.date, reverse=True
)
```